# Linux case statement always gives same result

Tags: linux, bash, case

I'm trying to check $VERSION with the case logic, but have some issue.

$VERSION can be "Connection refuced by host", "0,4,1,101 2013-05-18", or some other versions ex "0,4,1,102 2013-09-18"

I always seem to get to "some other problem" while $VERSION is "0,4,1,101 2013-05-18" in my tests...

```
    #!/bin/bash

HOSTNAME=$1
VERSION=$(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H servername01 -c checkversion)
echo "$VERSION" >> /var/log/dig-nscp-install.log

NOW=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d -- %H:%M')
LOGFILE=/var/log/dig-nscp-install.log

#if [ "$TRVER" == "Connection refused by host" ]; then
#       echo  "$NOW : Version $VERSION already installed on HOSTNAME!" >> /var/log/dig-nscp-install.log
#else
#       echo  "$NOW : Powershell install script initiated to install version $VERSION on $HOSTNAME!" >> /var/log/dig-nscp-install.log
#       /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H servername02 -t 300 -c install_nscp_0.4.101 -a $HOSTNAME
#
#fi

case $VERSION in
        "Connection refused by host")
                echo  "$NOW : Powershell script initiated to install version $VERSION on $HOSTNAME!" >> /var/log/dig-nscp-install.log
                ;;
        "0,4,1,101 2013-05-18")
                echo  "$NOW : Version $VERSION already installed on HOSTNAME!" >> /var/log/dig-nscp-install.log
                ;;
        *)
                echo "$NOW : Some other problem" >> /var/log/dig-nscp-install.log
                ;;

esac
```

Comment: All your code is a comment. Is that intended, or is that why it's not working?

Comment: try "echo $VERSION" before to case to see what it is. And $VERSION from what?

Comment: Better yet, try `printf '%q\n' "$VERSION"` before the `case` statement to really see what the content of `$VERSION` is (with all unprintable characters, if any!)

Comment: The code is in comment because I'm using else statements now. I just wanted to try using case for the first time... "Connection refused by host" is the result

Comment: Best guess, `VERSION` is set by something like `VERSION=$(cmd_that_read_from_network)`, and the value of `VERSION` ends up with a trailing carriage return.

Comment: @user2961029 - You might also be getting multiple line results from the command, which would throw off your case tests - you really need to output the full results of `VERSION` before case statement. You could try: `echo "$VERSION"|od -c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code (in bash) and there is nothing wrong with it.
It does what it is supposed to do perfectly :-)

The cause of the problem must be found in the code that assigns a value to "$VERSION".

If you update your question with the missing parts then I try to update my answer accordingly.

UPDATE: tested with `VERSION=$( echo "0,4,1,101 2013-05-18" )` and it works perfectly.

I can't run the nagios(?) program that you are running but it is certain that it gives a different output than what you expect (I will serch further and edit this answer accordingly).

Comment: Updated with the complete script. $VERSION is "Connection refused by host" in my logfile

Answer (score 1):

My guess is what @chepner mentioned in the comments.  You could try something like:

`"Connection refused by host"*)`  <== notice the `*`

The above should catch any errant carriage return or other weirdness.

If the CR *is* an issue where `VERSION` is set, you can alter its assignment by using `tr` to eliminate the unwanted character as such:

`VERSION=$(some command here|tr -d "\r")`